# Can't find GNU Icecat (or Firefox) source code

Tags: linux, firefox, internet, source, browser

I've been using GNU Icecat Browser (libre Firefox version made by Gnuzilla) for some weeks. I've been diving through its menus and I found an error:

When I get into the 'Customize Mode' (the one that lets you organize your toolbars and stuff), I find a little drop-down menu saying 'Themes', and an option called 'Get More Themes' inside it.

If I click it, it will redirect me [here][1], which will return an error. I want to modify the line of code of that redirection, in order to fix that URL, but I can't find it with `grep -Rli /icecat/addons/ /usr/share/`. Maybe am I searching in the wrong folder? Maybe the command is wrong?...

Comment: Answer: http://superuser.com/a/1045553/551116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icecat - https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/

Code - http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuzilla/

Scripts - http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnuzilla.git

Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives

source - https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.0b9/source/

Comment: `ls /home/username/Downloads

firefox-45.0b7                gnuzilla-38.3.0
firefox-45.0b9`

`username@computer:~$ sudo grep -Rlis '/icecat/themes' '/home/username/Downloads'
 
username@computer:~$`

Seems not to find anything, even having downloaded all the packages. This is strange, as I have Icecat properly installed (came by default), and I can't find this specific line. I also don't know were is my Icecat installed source code folder(s).

Comment: @xvlaze what are you trying to show me with that ls ?

Comment: Ah, just for showing the content of the folder where I downloaded all the packages. Just to let you know the folders I was grepping. Initially, I grepped in /usr/share because I thought there was were my Icecat default source code was, but there seems to be only a part. Sincerely, I'm completely lost: I have never tried to modify a big program, and I'm still getting used to all the folders and stuff in GNU/Linux distros.

Comment: Found it. I'm gonna post the solution in the Bugzilla mailing list. Do you want to be given credit for your collaboration?

Comment: no thanks, I just gave you some pointers, you did all the work.